# Javascript: Make new array out of nested json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, nested

I am getting data back which includes nested json objects and would like to make a new array containing those json objects. So if I am getting

```
[
   {
        "number": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "fruit": "apple",
                "meat": "chicken"
            },
            {
                "fruit": "orange",
                "meat": "pork"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I would like the new array to be

```
[
    {
        "fruit": "apple",
        "meat": "chicken"
    },
    {
        "fruit": "orange",
        "meat": "pork"
    }
]
```

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: The new array is just `data[0].products`. Can the data be more complicated than this?

Comment: I have been doing data.products instead of data [0].products. thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var A = [ { "number": 1, "products": [ { "fruit": "apple", "meat": "chicken" }, { "fruit": "orange", "meat": "pork" } ] } ];

var B = [];

A.forEach(function(number) {
    B = B.concat(number.products);
});

console.log(B);
```

[or test here](http://repl.it/BAA6)

Answer (score 0):

Use for loops to iterate over the data and place it in a new array.

```
var data = [{
    "number": 1,
    "products": [{
        "fruit": "apple",
        "meat": "chicken"
    }, {
        "fruit": "orange",
        "meat": "pork"
    }]
}],
allProducts = [];

for(var i=0;i< data.length; i++) {
    var products = data[0].products;
    for(var j=0;j< products.length; j++) {
        allProducts.push(products[j]);
    }
}
console.log(allProducts);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/rL3mpw74/)**

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you want to flatten the products into a single array - I'm probably wrong about that...  To test it, I moved a product into a separate parent in the data array.

```
var data = [
   {
        "number": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "fruit": "apple",
                "meat": "chicken"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "number": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "fruit": "orange",
                "meat": "pork"
            }    
        ]
    }
];

var products = data.reduce(function(x, y) {
    return x.products.concat(y.products);
});
```